# what directory should I use as my new hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, directory

I have a video server that runs linux server (no Grafical interface), which has 2 hard drives :

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop1                       7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop3                       7:3    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10707
loop4                       7:4    0  69.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19032
loop5                       7:5    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop6                       7:6    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11402
sda                         8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   237G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 118.5G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                      8:17   0   7.3T  0 part
```

the standard save directory is `/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos`
I want to change this directory to the another hard drive (sdb )
so I used :

```
mkdir /mnt/videodrive

mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/videodrive
```

which resulted :

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1                       7:1    0  69.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19032
loop2                       7:2    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop3                       7:3    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop4                       7:4    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11402
loop5                       7:5    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10707
loop6                       7:6    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
sda                         8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   237G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 118.5G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                      8:17   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/videodrive
```

can I just use /mnt/videodrive to store files on the another hard drive (sdb ) ?

Comment: If ext4, you also need to give yourself ownership & permissions. Similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mounted partition `sdb1`, which resides on your second drive `sdb`, to the folder `mnt/videodrive`, now, the entire contents of that partition is available in the folder where it is mounted. So also files you place in that folder, or in its subfolders, physically exist on the mounted drive.

If some application uses `/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos` as its standard directory, that application will continue writing files there. If you want the files to go to `mnt/videodrive`, there are two possibilities:

**Possibility 1: at the application level** Change the settings of your application to save files to the new location. How to change its standard save directory, and whether it will be easily possible, depends on the application. We have no information, so you will need to find out on your own how that can be achieved.

**Possibility 2: at the operating system level** Linux has powerfull symlinks. These allow to transparently redirect a file or an entire folder to another location. Thus, you could replace the folder `/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos` by a symbolic link that links through to `/mnt/videodrive`.

This is how this can be done. First command deletes the `video` folder under `/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/`. Make sure you empty that folder first. Second command creates the symbolic link, with the same name. For practical purposes, this symbolic link feels and behaves like a folder.

```
rmdir /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos
ln -s /mnt/videodrive /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos
```

In very specific cases, a link may not work. In that case, a `mount -bind` [can be used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280849/mount-bind-with-full-ownership-and-permissions).

Comment: why sda is mounted  on  /boot directory while when I do pwd it doesn't show this /boot directory, and same time when I should mount it should be  from /dev/sda or dev/sdb  and also this dev isn't shown by pwd command

Comment: Not sda, but sda2 is mounted to /boot. ls /boot will show the contents of /boot. dev's are never shown in your pwd command. Only directories and files are.